# Definitions of Sobolev Spaces - are they the same?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, schwartz-space

I have read two definitions of Sobolev spaces.

> **Definition 1:** We let $\lambda$ denote $\lambda^s(\xi)=(1+|\xi|^2)^\frac{s}{2}$ for $s \in \Bbb R$, $\xi \in \Bbb R^n$. We say that $u \in H^s$, if $u \in S'$ and $$||\lambda^s \hat{u} ||_2= (2 \pi)^{-n} \int (1 + |\xi|^2 )^s |\hat{u}(\xi)|^2 \, d \xi  < \infty$$ under the identification of $L^2$ in $ S'$. $S'$ is the [dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space#Dual_space) of the  [Schawrtz Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) on $\Bbb R^n$, known as [temperate distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform) , with respect to the norm on Schawrtz space.

What differentiates this definition to the second definition:

> **Definition 2:**  On the Schwartz space, the Sobolev space $W^s$ is the completion of $S$ with respect to the $s$-norm.
>     $$||u||_s^2 := (2 \pi)^{-n} \int (1 + |\xi|^2 )^s |\hat{u}(\xi)|^2 \, d \xi $$

Is that the first definition is working with *topologicial dual on Schwartz space* whilst latter is working directly with Schwartz space.

> Are these the same? Why do we have a $H$ snd a $W$?

Sources: First definition is from Xavier's, Introudction to Pseudodifferential Manifolds, Second Definition is From [Ebert's notes.](https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/jeber_02/skripten/mainfile.pdf) 
I am quite confused, as both of these definitions do not appear in [Sobolev spaces.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space)

---

As suggested by user Rhys:

So we have a map $S \rightarrow S'$, given $$\phi \mapsto  u_\phi= \left( \psi \mapsto \int \psi \bar{\phi} \right)$$
$$||\hat{u}_\phi||_2 = ||u_\phi||$$
by construction. It suffices to show $S$ in the $||\cdot||_2$ norm is

(i) Dense in $H^s$
(ii) and $H^s$ is complete.
Are these true?

Comment: You did not actually pose any question, but I guess what you want to know is why and how these two definition describe the same thing?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot.

Comment: $\mathcal{S}'$ is usually the topological dual space of $\mathcal{S}$. Are you sure you mean to write that $\mathcal{S}'$ is the space of seminorms on $\mathcal{S}$? (this is not even a vector space since seminorms must be non-negative)

Comment: Thanks Rhys, I have edited.

Comment: I don't understand. You wrote the exact same integrals. Why are you surprised that they define the same thing?

Comment: Here's a sketch of how to prove this. First check that definition $1$ gives you a complete space. Secondly, notice that you can consider $\mathcal{S}$ as a subset of $\mathcal{S}'$ by identifying it with its image under the map $\phi \mapsto \Phi$ where $\Phi(\psi) := \int \phi \psi dx$. Finally, check that under this identification $\mathcal{S}$ is a dense subset of $H^s$ (as defined by definition $1$). This gives that $H^s$ as in definition 1 is the completion that appears in definition $2$.

Comment: @RhysSteele, why is there a difference in $H^s$ and $W^s$ notation?

Comment: I'd normally expect to see $W^{s,2}$ instead of $W^s$ but this might just be a choice on the part of the author. Btw when I gave you a sketch proof, I meant for you to try to do those things, not just add them to the question. Have you tried to do either? If so you should include your efforts in the question.

Comment: Schwartz functions are, in certain contexts, the "best" functions: they are smooth and "finite at infinity" in many different ways. Thus when you want to define a function space its not a bad idea to start with the Schwartz functions and express a norm or locally convex topology that is adapted to your problem. Then take the completion wrt this norm, you should still be able to understand the elements of the thus constructed space as functions. This is what you are doing in the second definition.

Comment: In your second definition you are going "the other direction", instead of starting with the most finite functions, introducing a norm and then seeing what other functions you can approximate in this norm with these finite functions, you start with a space of more "infinite" functions, in this case the $L^2$ space. These functions are too infinite for your purpose and so you introduce a finiteness condition that not necessarily every function fulfils, and consider your new space to be the space of those functions finite wrt the condition.

Comment: If you want to see that the two definitions are equivalent you need to consider the inclusion of $S$ into $L^2$ and first note that every function in $S$ fulfils the finiteness condition, ie your inclusion is actually into the space $H^s$. What you then do is check that the norms are the same, so this inclusion is isometric. If you check that $H^s$ is complete you can extend your isometric inclusion to one $W^s\to H^s$. Then verify that $S$ is dense in $H^s$ to see that this map is an invertible isometry.

Comment: Thanks a lot s.harp! @Rhys, sorry that i sound like I just wanted you to write up. In fact I do want to work this out some time, but I have been working on an unrelated project recently - and so I just wanted an authoritative reference to tell me if i'm on the right track (i.e. what I am going to prove is even a correct statement).